# MYSQL Searching multiple tables with different columns using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, search, multiple-tables, sql-like

I need to be able to do a search on multiple tables and return all parts that are similar to the searched term.  My problem is that the tables have varying amounts of columns.  They do have columns with similar names though. First the PHP checks the "productnumber" table to find all parts with the similar part number.  Then it searches through each table to find a matching number.

Right now if a similar part is found in the Components table, it will not display any parts found from Adapters or Connectors.  Instead of selecting all columns and neglecting to search all tables I'd like to search for these three columns which are found in all three tables and return results found in all tables:

part_num

image

page

```
if(isset($_GET['num'])) {
$num = $_GET['num'];
$numresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productnumber WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");

  if ($numresult) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($numresult)) {

        if ($row["title"] == "connectors") {
            $numtitle = "connectors";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM connectors WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

        if ($row["title"] == "adapters") {
            $numtitle = "adapters";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adapters WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

        if ($row["title"] == "components") {
            $numtitle = "components";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM components WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

    }

  }

}
```

Any help regarding my question would be greatly appreciated :]

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($numresult)) {

        if ($row["title"] == "connectors") {
            $numtitle = "connectors";
            $result[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM connectors WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

        if ($row["title"] == "adapters") {
            $numtitle = "adapters";
            $result[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adapters WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

        if ($row["title"] == "components") {
            $numtitle = "components";
            $result[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM components WHERE part_num LIKE '%$num%'");
        }

    }
```

you have to make another loop to retrieve data from **result** array

Comment: How might you loop through the result array and echo values in the same way you would with a mysql query?